# Unstack doesn't work anymore with non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas

I previously asked a question about restructuring dataframes in python, see here:

['restructure' dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261062/restructure-dataframe-in-python)

User Jezrael answerd the question and the solution worked fine until now.

This is the code I'm using:

```
df1 = df.set_index('FAULTCODE', append=True).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
restructure1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')

df = df.join(df1)
```

Which now throws this error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I kind of understand why it throws this error (my index isn't a unique values, which is indeed the case), but I'm not sure why it worked until now. Nothing's changed in the data. So I'm wondering if something changed in Python's settings and if I can get this working again?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out that something was changed to the SQL-db from which the data was imported. Nothing apparent was changed to the data but the infrastructure behind it did change, which caused trouble with the indices.